Blazor Server SignalR HubConnection wrapper doesn't SendAsync to Hub function
I was using HubConnection in my component in order to user real-time fucntionnality. But I would like to test my component so then I wrapper my HubConnection like this:
public class HubConnectionService : IHubConnectionService, IAsyncDisposable
{
    private HubConnection _hubConnection;
    private readonly NavigationManager _navigationManager;

public HubConnectionService(NavigationManager navigationManager) 
{
    _navigationManager = navigationManager;
}

public void Init(string path)
{
    _hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
        .WithUrl(_navigationManager.ToAbsoluteUri(path))
        .WithAutomaticReconnect()
        .Build();
}

public void On<T>(string methodName, Func<T, Task> handler) => _hubConnection.On(methodName, handler);
public void On(string methodName, Func<Task> handler) => _hubConnection.On(methodName, handler);

public async Task SendAsync(string method, params object[] args)
{
    await _hubConnection.SendAsync(method, args);
}

public async Task StartAsync()
{
    await _hubConnection.StartAsync();
}

public bool IsConnected => _hubConnection.State == HubConnectionState.Connected;

public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
{
    if (_hubConnection is not null)
    {
        await _hubConnection.DisposeAsync();
    }
}

}
This is my component now:
@page "/Jouer/{Id:int}"

@attribute [Authorize()]

@inject IGameService GameService
@inject IHttpAccessorService HttpAccessorService
@inject IReadyGameService ReadyGameService
@inject NavigationManager Navigation
@inject IHubConnectionService HubConnectionService

@if (Game == null)
{
    <Loader/>
}
else
{
    <div class="container">
        <Plate Game="Game" />
        <div class="centered-container question-component">
            @if (Game.Type == GameOnline && UsersReady != null && UsersReady.Any(d => d.Value == false))
            {
                @if (!UserReady)
                {
                    <div class="">
                        <InputCheckbox @bind-Value="UserReady" @onclick="() => UserIsReady()" /> Je suis prêt(e)
                    </div>
                }
                else
                {
                    <p>Vous avez indiqué que vous êtes prêt(e)!</p>
                }
                @foreach (var user in UsersReady)
                {
                    <div class="d-flex align-items-center mb-2">
                        @if (user.Value)
                        {
                            <i class="bi bi-check-circle-fill me-2" style="color:green;font-size:1.5rem;"></i>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <i class="bi bi-x-circle-fill me-2" style="color:red;font-size:1.5rem;"></i>
                        }
                        <h4>@user.Key.Email</h4>
                    </div>
                }
            }
            else
            {
                <GameQuestion Game="Game" GameChanged="OnGameChanged" />
            }
        </div>
    </div>
}

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    private GameDto Game { get; set; }
    private Dictionary<UserDto, bool> UsersReady { get; set; } = new();
    private bool UserReady { get; set; } = false; 

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        HubConnectionService.Init("/userhub");
        HubConnectionService.On<string>("UserReadyChanged", async (userId) =>
        {
            var userKey = UsersReady.Keys
                .First(u => u.Id == userId);
            UsersReady[userKey] = true;
            await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
        });
        await HubConnectionService.StartAsync();
        await HubConnectionService.SendAsync("UpdateUserPath", Navigation.Uri);

        Game = await GameService.GetAsync(Id);

        RefreshUsersReady();
    }

    private void RefreshUsersReady()
    {
        if (Game.Type == GameOnline)
        {
            var ready = ReadyGameService.GetAll(Id);

            UsersReady.Clear();

            foreach (var player in Game.Players)
            {
                var dto = ready.FirstOrDefault(ready => ready.UserId == player.UserId);
                UsersReady.Add(player.User!, dto == null ? false : dto.Ready);
            }
            var userReady = UsersReady.FirstOrDefault(ur => ur.Key.Id == HttpAccessorService.GetConnectedUserId());
            UserReady = userReady.Value == true ? true : false;
        }
    }

    private async Task OnGameChanged(GameDto game)
    {
        Game = game;
        await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    }

    private async Task UserIsReady()
    {
        var readyGame = new ReadyGameDto()
        {
            Game = Game,
            GameId = Id,
            UserId = HttpAccessorService.GetConnectedUserId()
        };
        UserReady = true;
        await ReadyGameService.Add(readyGame);
        var userKey = UsersReady.Keys
                .First(u => u.Id == HttpAccessorService.GetConnectedUserId());
        UsersReady[userKey] = true;
        await HubConnectionService.SendAsync("NotifyUserReady", Id, HttpAccessorService.GetConnectedUserId());
    }
}

The porblem is that when I wrapper the HubConnection, the SendAsync is triggered in the service, but not in my implemented Hub class to send to all client. So I wonder where is my error? What should I to in order to user a HubConnection Wrapper and to make it work like when there was no wrapper.

Try _hubConnection.SendCoreAsync.

What you mean about it, your codes are using the HubConnectionService's SendAsync method,  SendAsync should be triggered in the service. Could you please tell me what's happened? Did the hub method not triggered?
